# VMWare, Virtualization, Windows 2008 and Performance

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, virtualization, performance

When you are looking at the performance monitoring tools in Windows 2008 server is the CPU stats that you see based on the real CPU or the fake CPU (your share of the CPU)? CPU reports to be a Xeon X7350.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off the usual disclaimer: VMWare is a company, not a product. Name the product that you're referring to, because they vary in their operation quite drastically.

The stats within the guest operating system are only what's visible to that OS. It has no visibility of the load that other VMs on the same host may be generating, so you're only seeing your slice of the pie. That said, in an uncontended (low-load) environment, what you see is probably quite close to what's available. But if overall host load or individual VM load is high you're almost certainly not seeing the complete picture from within the VM.

The CPU ID that's reported is usually the actual CPU of the host machine, unless CPU masking is being used (not that likely). You can't tell how many sockets or cores are available on the host via the guest, however.

Comment: Not sure which of the VMWare products this company is using. I have to get access to the real machine. I'm hoping the will increase our part of the RAM from 2Gig to 4Gig. But I have to find out how much total RAM is on the actual box.

Answer (score 1):

If Windows2008 is a VM, then you get CPU usage of the virtual CPU.